# Java : Deploy restful web service without jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

Thanks in advance. I am new in web services , when i try to deploy the restful web service using java , it will generate an exception. I am follow the [RESTful Java with JAX-RS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158057.do) to learn web services, according to this book chapter 3 ,i try to build the example , after deploying the example it will generate the exception , i know , i miss something , but i don't know what i missing. following is my code of example .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>RestfulTest</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.restfultest.controller.ShoppingApplication</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Following is the class

```
 public class ShoppingApplication extends Application {

private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
public ShoppingApplication() {
    singletons.add(new CustomerResources());
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return empty;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
  }
```

when try to deploy the application following the exception occur.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.restfultest.controller.ShoppingApplication cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
```

this is silly question i know , `ShoppingApplication` is not the servlet class but accordin to this book ,it is servlet class. to call this services , i use `chrome` restful client. Please suggest me how to use chrome restful client and how to send `XML` or `JSON` request using this client.

Comment: I assume it to be a problem with the Application class import. Can you share the imports. You may be referring to an Application class which is not javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

Comment: following is the import of class import `java.util.HashSet; import java.util.Set; import javax.ws.rs.core.Application; import com.resfultest.service.CustomerResources; `. But i think, this is the problem of servlet , because when i call , the application not found any servlet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are telling that your class is a servlet which is not true. Thre must be a problem in the documentation you are following. Take a look at this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
<servlet-name>com.restfultest.controller.ShoppingApplication</servlet-name>
```

and no `servlet-class`. The Jersey project has a good reference for the [various options of deploying JAX-RS 1.1 applications](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e188), including [this specific case](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e223).

Also note that this only works in Servlet 3.0. In earlier servlet specs, you have to provide an actual servlet class that implements a JAX-RS container, like [Jersey's ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e233).

Comment: how to send `xml` request using `chrome restful` client?

Comment: That depends on what "chrome restful client" is, and this is unrelated and should be its own question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem occur because the `Tomcat Container` does not aware about `JAX-RS` . So to define the implementation of `JAX-RS` we need to add third party libraries . When i add the `Jersey` lib and add the `Jersey` servlet definition in container , my example run successfully. Following is the `web.xml

```
...............................
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.restfultest.controller.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
..................................
```